# How to add a language pack without adding a keyboard layout

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

How to add a language pack without adding a keyboard layout?
How to remove a keyboard layout without removing the corresponding language pack?

If several keyboard are set up for a language pack, its possible to remove them until there is only one remaining, and then from that point the 'remove' option becomes greyed.

Context:

When I add a language pack (to get spellchecking, voice inputs, locale settings), windows automatically adds a keyboard layout corresponding to the language. (French in my case, ie 'azerty')

My laptop has an american keyboard, and with the international setting, keys like ^`'" are turned into dead keys, which makes it easy for me to type stuff like éèêï, basically removing the need for me to have a french keyboard.

I usually would not mind it, but in my case its annoying because I frequently have to switch my input language between english and japanese, which requires a keyboard switch. With french enabled, I have to press shift + alt twice to go from japanese to english, but only once for going from english to japanese.

I'm considering adding a dummy language so that I would consistently need to press shift + alt twice to switch between japanese and english, but I would much rather remove the french layout.

Comment: Please leave a comment if you are downvoting me

Comment: I upvoted you! Word forced me to install French and I absolutely hate the French keyboard.

Comment: Richard, I couldn't find a way to remove the keyboard per language pack BUT... I could add the English keyboard to the French language pack and remove the French layout so now I have 2 keyboards that are exactly the same layout (US and US)

Answer (score 3):

You may assign a shortcut to a keyboard layout for quickly switching layouts.

Finding it will require some clicking.
You will find it in
*Settings > Time & Language > Language > Spelling, typing, & keyboard settings >
Advanced keyboard settings > Language bar options > Advanced Key Settings*.

Click a layout and press *Change Key Sequence...*

Comment: Thanks, its not fully answering the question, but its a nice alternative