# How to change to wlan report output language?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, language

TL;DR: is it possible to change the language of the wlanreport without changing the display language of the system?

My default language is Czech, I use also French and Polish keyboard layouts and I prefer not to change this. However, for debugging, the wlan report in Czech is not very useful - trying to figure out the original English messages is annoying and what I can find in Czech is often insufficient. Anyway, it's useless for IT support here in France. However, neither in the [documentation for Netsh](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-contexts) nor in the one for [wlanreport](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/analyze-the-wireless-network-report-76da0daa-1db2-6049-d154-7bb679eb03ed) I didn't find an output language option. [Changing language for a single application seems impossible](https://superuser.com/q/1435601/373304). For now, my workflow is following:

1. [Change the display language, installing language and language pack](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-properly-change-system-default-language-windows-10) if necessary
2. Log out (and wait quite a long time)
3. Log in (and wait quite a long time)
4. generate wlan report
5. change the display language back to Czech
6. Log out (and wait quite a long time)
7. Log in (and wait once again quite a long time)
8. If the wlanreport language was English, purge it from the system to renew my keyboard settings

Even if it was possible [to install a language without installing corresponding keyboard layout](https://superuser.com/q/1409484/373304), this workflow is too slow.

Comment: I'm almost certain what you want is not possible.

Comment: @DavidPostill: if it is really not possible, I would (even though not happily) accept it as an answer. I would like some reasons for believing that the solution is impossible and workarounds unlikely (except for the tricks to live with more keyboard layouts than I need, as in one of the linked questions' answer) though.